# How to check if an Authenticated User has a specific claim AND the a Route segment is the same as the UserId?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, attributes, middleware, claims

I'm trying to see if it's possible in an ASP.NET-Core 2 web app, that if a User is authenticated in a request, we can also check in some Filter/ActionMethod Attribute:

- They have a specific claim
- The route has an `string` `id` segment (e.g. `HttpPut[("{id}")]` ) and that `id` segment needs to match the Auth'd User's Id.
- Request includes a JWT header with the `bearer token` in it, which is used to 'create' the Authenticated Identity (which works 100% fine).

e.g.

- `HTTP PUT /accounts/PureKrome` | User `Id:PureKrome` | Claim: Irrelivant. => Can continue. [You are updating yourself. Don't need any special claim when updating yourself].
- `HTTP PUT /accounts/PureKrome` | User is Anonymous or `Id:SomethingElse` | Claim: irrelivant => Failure (Forbidden response) [Someone else is trying to update you and doesn't have the correct overriding claim. So fail]
- `HTTP PUT /accounts/SomeoneElse` | User is `Id:PureKrome` | Claim: correct claim. => Can continue  [Trying to update a different user BUT you have a claim that allows you to do that]

Right now, I do this in my `ActionMethod` code ... one of the first things. So I was just curious to see if this could be achieved using an Attribute that decorates the ActionMethod, instead.

Answer (score 1):

That isn’t actually too complicated. All you need to do is have an [authorization filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0#authorization-filters) that looks at the route values and then checks it with the current user.

Something simple like this should already work fine:

```
public class ValidateUserIdRouteAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        var requestedUserId = context.RouteData.Values["id"] as string;
        var currentUserId = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (requestedUserId != currentUserId &&
            !user.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "may-edit" && c.Value == requestedUserId))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

And used on a route it would look like this:

```
[ValidateUserIdRoute]
[HttpGet("/account/update/{id}")]
public IActionResult UpdateAccount(string id)
{
    // …
}
```

That’s all. If you have authentication set up properly, the Bearer token will be used to authenticate the user which may or may not set up the claims properly, and then you just check against those claims to see if accessing the route is allowed or not.

Of course, you can expand on this idea and add some more functionality to it, e.g. support different route data keys or something like that.